# One position right barrel shift using ALU Operators?

Tags: operators, bit-shift, bitwise-operators

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to perform a shift right on an 8 bit binary value using only ALU Operators (NOT, OR, AND, XOR, ADD, SUB)

```
Example:

input:  00110101
output: 10011010
```

I have been able to implement a shift left by just adding the 8 bit binary value with itself since a shift left is equivalent to multiplying by 2. However, I can't think of a way to do this for shift right.

The only method I have come up with so far is to just perform 7 left barrel shifts. Is this the only way?

Comment: probably you want *rotation*. Rotate is different from shift.

Comment: Yah, that's called *rotate right*, not *shift*.

Comment: The shift-left implementation is a true shift though, as it shifts in a 0 and discards (overflows) the top bit.

Comment: might just be a matter of vocabulary, or maybe my explanation was a bit confusing. Here is a wiki of what I was trying to explain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial to see that this cannot be done with `{AND, OR, XOR, NOT}`. For all these operators, outbit[N] depends on inbit1[N] and inbit2[N] **only**. AND adds a dependency on inbit1[N]..inbit1[0] and inbit2[N]..inbit2[0]. However, in your case you require a dependency on inbit[N+1]. Therefore, it follows that if there is any solution, it must include a SUB.

However, `A - B` is just `A + (-B)` which is `A + ((B XOR 11111111) +1)`. Hence, if there was a solution using SUB, it could be rewritten as a solution using ADD and XOR instead. As we've shown, those operators are insufficient. Hence, the set `{ADD, OR, XOR, NOT, ADD, SUB}` is insufficient too.

Comment: thats what I thought. I thought there was possibly some kind of mask that could be used and then manipulated. It's just that when I was working with MIPS assembly, the book claimed it could do divide (if its a power of two) in 1 clock cycle. I'm thinking this may be because of a hardware shifter.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Hardware barrel shifters are quite common, and not too complex (apparently).